# Stuck after printing 'Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7'

Tags: tensorflow

I can't receive any log after 'Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7'.
Sometimes is works after about 1 hour,but Sometimes it hangs on even 1-2 days without no logs

Environment:
Ubuntu 14.04.5
tensorflow 1.14.0
python 2.7.6

Answer (score 0):

Me too, when using Google AI platform. This is before any of my code executes. Oddly the message "Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7" is in the log twice. My config was:

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  masterType: n1-highmem-8
  masterConfig:
    acceleratorConfig:
      count: 1
      type: NVIDIA_TESLA_P100
```

Comment: Using  tensorflow version 1.14

Comment: This symptom can be caused by: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32017, but I'm not using sloppy=True, so mine is probably a different problem.